# Don't Allow Website automated Redirect Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am really sorry if the question is incomplete or unhelpful.
I am slightly new at this.

I just started using scrapy for scraping data. The issue that I am facing at the moment is: when i try to scrape data, a website redirect's me to a particular page.

**I intend to stop the website from redirecting to that particular page.**

To be honest i am not sure if it's even possible or not.

What I have tried so far is:

1. Following the redirect and from there using a href link provided to go to the desired page.The issue in this case is that site follow's a loop and redirects me back to the same page.
2. REDIRECT_ENABLED = False in setting's. The issue in this case is that the **scraper** exit's and the script stop's.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Could you maybe include the code that you suspect to be causing this redirect? As well as specifics on what page you're being redirected to and such? Is it a link on the page you're scraping or something else?

Comment: @Tresdon - http://www.justdial.com/Delhi-NCR/Ceramic-Tile-Dealers/ct-17716. It is happening when i try to scrape data from this url.

Comment: you need to share your code.